# How to delete permanetly a change set from Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

Late last night I ended up checking in the production login details into the repository. As I am right now the only developer working on this, it is not a big deal but in future it is not great having the production details exposed.

What I ended up doing was going on the server:

```
hg clone <old repo> <new repo> -r <revision>
```

to clone only up to the revision before the bad commit and deleted the

I tested it and it seems fine. I thought I ask better here to be sure, have I really made sure that there is no hidden history or hidden foot print lying around to expose the content of that bad commit?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `clone` command will work, but if your repository has multiple branches, that clone will not include them. So unless you carefully pull those in individually, you may have lost more than you intended. Likely this is not what you want...

The easiest way to remove a revision is using the `strip` command from the [MQ extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Strip).  You can use this in combination with the `rebase` command ([Rebase extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension)) to remove a changeset that already has children that you want to preserve; first `rebase` the children onto the parent, and then `strip` the offending changeset.

Do take care though that these are history modifying operations, so *if the changeset is already shared with other users, it will still be in their repository*. Even after they pull. They will need to repeat your steps to get rid of them, which is quite a pain in the ass. The change could even accidentally end up back in the main repository that way. (Note: this applies to your `clone` method as well.)

So if you need to do this, best to instruct all your users to make a fresh clone, or at least strip the change, and make a hook to prevent the changeset from being reintroduced. If you can’t contact and/or trust all your users (e.g. because it is open source), probably it is better to leave the changeset there and just change your production credentials. It’s already out in the wild anyway.

In the future there will be a better way to do remove or alter changesets with the “obsoletion” feature, slated for Mercurial 2.4. Once that is fully implemented, when users pull from your repository their repository’s history can automatically update accordingly. So keep an eye out for that feature.

Comment: Since I was the only user, nobody else has any history. :) I was more concerned about the future once more developers would join the team. I tried Strip before, but despite having `mq = ` in my hg.config file, i wasn't able to activate the extension.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry. After deleting `<old repo>`, it's definitely gone. Although a forensic expert might still find something interesting in the deleted blocks on disk.

Comment: +1 from me and I choose the other one as answer for future reference. Thanks